# How to force a qt version to be installed

Tags: 16.04, apt, kde, qt5, kde5

After the last qt update, I have a conflict between my qt versions.
A part of the qt libraries come from ubuntu Xenial repo and the other part from neon Xenial repo. I cannot start kde anymore due to this conflict.

Ubuntu xenial seems to use qt 5.11.1 and neon qt 5.11.0.
So I would like to downgrade all my qt lib to 5.11.0

Thank you in advance for any hints you might be able to provide.

dpkg -l:

```
ii  libqt5concurrent5:amd64                         5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build55                       amd64        Qt 5 concurrent module
ii  libqt5core5a:amd64                              5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build55                       amd64        Qt 5 core module
ii  libqt5dbus5:amd64                               5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build55                       amd64        Qt 5 D-Bus module
ii  libqt5designer5:amd64                           5.11.1-2+16.04+xenial+build35                            amd64        Qt 5 designer module
ii  libqt5designercomponents5:amd64                 5.11.1-2+16.04+xenial+build35                            amd64        Qt 5 Designer components module
ii  libqt5gui5:amd64                                5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build55                       amd64        Qt 5 GUI module
ii  libqt5help5:amd64                               5.11.1-2+16.04+xenial+build35                            amd64        Qt 5 help module
ii  libqt5multimedia5:amd64                         5.11.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build25                        amd64        Qt 5 Multimedia module
ii  libqt5multimedia5-plugins:amd64                 5.11.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build25                        amd64        Qt 5 Multimedia module plugins
ii  libqt5multimediagsttools5:amd64                 5.11.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build25                        amd64        Qt 5 Multimedia Gst Tools module
ii  libqt5multimediaquick5:amd64                    5.11.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build25                        amd64        Qt 5 Multimedia Quick module
ii  libqt5multimediawidgets5:amd64                  5.11.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build25                        amd64        Qt 5 Multimedia Widgets module
ii  libqt5network5:amd64                            5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build55                       amd64        Qt 5 network module
ii  libqt5opengl5:amd64                             5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build55                       amd64        Qt 5 OpenGL module
ii  libqt5opengl5-dev:amd64                         5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build55                       amd64        Qt 5 OpenGL library development files
ii  libqt5positioning5:amd64                        5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build35                       amd64        Qt Positioning module
ii  libqt5printsupport5:amd64                       5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build55                       amd64        Qt 5 print support module
ii  libqt5qml-graphicaleffects                      5.6.1-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~2                          all          transitional dummy package for Qt 5 Graphical Effects module
ii  libqt5qml5:amd64                                5.11.1-2+16.04+xenial+build42                            amd64        Qt 5 QML module
ii  libqt5quick5:amd64                              5.11.1-2+16.04+xenial+build42                            amd64        Qt 5 Quick library
ii  libqt5quickcontrols2-5:amd64                    5.11.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build27                        amd64        Qt 5 Quick Controls 2 library
ii  libqt5quickparticles5:amd64                     5.11.1-2+16.04+xenial+build42                            amd64        Qt 5 Quick particles module
ii  libqt5quicktemplates2-5:amd64                   5.11.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build27                        amd64        Qt 5 Quick Templates 2 library
ii  libqt5quicktest5:amd64                          5.11.1-2+16.04+xenial+build42                            amd64        Qt 5 Quick Test library
ii  libqt5quickwidgets5:amd64                       5.11.1-2+16.04+xenial+build42                            amd64        Qt 5 Quick Widgets library
ii  libqt5script5:amd64                             5.11.0+dfsg-0neon+16.04+xenial+build31                   amd64        Qt 5 script module
ii  libqt5scripttools5:amd64                        5.11.0+dfsg-0neon+16.04+xenial+build31                   amd64        Qt 5 script tools module
ii  libqt5sensors5:amd64                            5.11.1-2+16.04+xenial+build29                            amd64        Qt Sensors module
ii  libqt5sql5:amd64                                5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build55                       amd64        Qt 5 SQL module
ii  libqt5sql5-mysql:amd64                          5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build55                       amd64        Qt 5 MySQL database driver
ii  libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64                         5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build55                       amd64        Qt 5 SQLite 3 database driver
ii  libqt5svg5:amd64                                5.11.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build23                        amd64        Qt 5 SVG module
ii  libqt5svg5-dev:amd64                            5.11.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build23                        amd64        Qt 5 SVG module development files
ii  libqt5test5:amd64                               5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build55                       amd64        Qt 5 test module
ii  libqt5texttospeech5:amd64                       5.11.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build13                        amd64        Speech library for Qt - libraries
ii  libqt5waylandclient5:amd64                      5.11.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build34                        amd64        QtWayland client library
ii  libqt5waylandcompositor5:amd64                  5.11.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build34                        amd64        QtWayland compositor library
ii  libqt5webchannel5:amd64                         5.11.1-2+16.04+xenial+build29                            amd64        Web communication library for Qt
ii  libqt5webengine-data                            5.11.0+dfsg-0neon+16.04+xenial+build60                   amd64        Web content engine library for Qt - Data
ii  libqt5webengine5:amd64                          5.11.0+dfsg-0neon+16.04+xenial+build60                   amd64        Web content engine library for Qt
ii  libqt5webenginecore5:amd64                      5.11.0+dfsg-0neon+16.04+xenial+build60                   amd64        Web content engine library for Qt - Core
ii  libqt5webenginewidgets5:amd64                   5.11.0+dfsg-0neon+16.04+xenial+build60                   amd64        Web content engine library for Qt - Widget
ii  libqt5webkit5:amd64                             5.212.0~alpha2-12+16.04+xenial+build36                   amd64        Web content engine library for Qt
ii  libqt5webkit5-dev:amd64                         5.212.0~alpha2-12+16.04+xenial+build36                   amd64        Web content engine library for Qt - development files
ii  libqt5widgets5:amd64                            5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build55                       amd64        Qt 5 widgets module
ii  libqt5x11extras5:amd64                          5.11.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build23                        amd64        Qt 5 X11 extras
ii  libqt5x11extras5-dev:amd64                      5.11.0-0neon+16.04+xenial+build23                        amd64        Qt 5 X11 extras development files
ii  libqt5xml5:amd64                                5.11.1+dfsg-2+16.04+xenial+build55                       amd64        Qt 5 XML module
ii  libqt5xmlpatterns5:amd64                        5.11.1-2+16.04+xenial+build32                            amd64        Qt 5 XML patterns module
ii  libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev:amd64                    5.11.1-2+16.04+xenial+build32                            amd64        Qt 5 XML patterns development files
```

inxi -Sxxxr:

```
System:    Host: PDEMU1CML000101 Kernel: 4.8.17-040817-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 6.2.0)
           Desktop: Gnome 3.18.5 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3) info: gnome-shell dm: gdm3 Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Repos:     Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list
           deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
           deb http://archive.neon.kde.org/release xenial main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-xenial.list
           deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu xenial main
           deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main contrib universe restricted
           deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main contrib universe restricted
           deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main contrib universe restricted
           deb http://packages.ros.org.ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/ros/ubuntu/ xenial main
           deb https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com/atlassian/hipchat-apt-client xenial main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
           deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
           deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list
           deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
           deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
           deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

Comment: Please install `inxi` and then add the output of  `inxi -Sxxxr` to your question?

Comment: @DKBose I edited to question with the inxi output